# linux compatible rack server

Tags: linux, tomcat, rack

My boss wants to buy a rack server. I'll have to move there couple of .jsp and .php websites that are now hosted on shared linux servers.

I would guess all modern servers are compatible with linux, is that so? What linux version would you recommend to run Apache/MySQL/php/Tomcat stack?

Answer (score 2):

Virtually all modern servers have drivers for Linux, but simply check the manufacturer's support site before you buy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all modern servers are compatible with at least some version of Linux. You should find out what distribution you'll be using (Red Hat? CentOS? Debian?) and check with the manufacturers to be sure that this specific distro is supported. Some hardware requires proprietary drivers that can, for instance, be avaiable only in RPM format for SuSE or something.